# Where do I add code that would manipulate the text of a blog post in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Here is the code that works for me in views/posts/show.html.erb file:

```
<% require 'rmmseg' %>
<% RMMSeg::Dictionary.load_dictionaries %>
<% text = "你好" %>
<% algor = RMMSeg::Algorithm.new(@post.content) %>
<% loop do %>
    <% tok = algor.next_token %>
    <% break if tok.nil? %>
    <% text2 = tok.text.force_encoding('UTF-8') %>
    <%= "#{text2}" %>
<% end %>
```

I am new to rails so I need help knowing where to put this code, or similar, in the framework so that it saves the post with the spaces in the database. Should it be in the controller? If so, how would I do it?

I was trying and failing with this:

```
def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])

require 'rmmseg'
  RMMSeg::Dictionary.load_dictionaries

    algor = RMMSeg::Algorithm.new(@post.content)
    loop do
    tok = algor.next_token
    break if tok.nil?
    text2 = tok.text.force_encoding('UTF-8')
    @post.content = "#{text2}"
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I obviously have know idea what I am doing yet.

Comment: It's not immediately clear what you mean by "manipulate the text of a blog post". How exactly are you wanting to manipulate it?

Comment: In this case I want to add spaces to any Chinese text. (chinese text doesn't usually have spaces, but I want to add spaces to make it easier for a beginner to read it.)

Comment: Have you tried the string.gsub method? For instance `text.gsub(/(.­{1})/, '\1 ')` (where text is your Chinese text) will add a space in between each character. That line would go in your view code wherever you wish to display the desired text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I called the [Rails Hotline](http://rails.pockethotline.com) and they gave me the hint to put it in the model using a callback (before_save, after_save, etc.)

That worked for me.